# How to build tapestry Tab component?

Tags: tapestry

Anybody know a working example of Tab component in Tapestry?
I found following examples on the net but either the source is not attached or the project is not working with latest Tatestry  5.3 release
1)  http://tawus.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-tab-panel-for-tapestry/ :- No source code 
2)  http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToCreateATabPanel  :- It has dependency on another project which is discontinued
3)  chenillekit.org/chenillekit-tapestry/ref/org/chenillekit/tapestry/core/components/TabSet.html  :- Not working with latest tapestry release
Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

The tapestry5-jquery project has a tab component. See the demo here: http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsjquerytabs

This project is very mature and widely adopted with the tapestry community and I would recommend on using their tab panel component.

Cheers

Comment: except that would require using jquery instead of the default prototypejs